# Issue with deprecation while running python bot

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api

When I run the code, it is telling me "openai.Completion is unsupported". I tried to fix it using "openai.ChatCompletion", but that too is unsupported.

I tried to use the alternatives I described earlier but they are not working too. So, I tried to downgrade to an older version of openAI but that is throwing some errors of it's own. I have tried doing that for atleast a total of 4-5 hours and I am unable to figure it out. In conclusion, my best bet to get this bot running is to simply use the latest version. I am attaching the code below:

```
import openai
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

openai.api_key = 'my_api_key'

def get_response(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
      engine="text-davinci-003",
      prompt=prompt,
      temperature=0.5,
      max_tokens=100
    )
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

def generate_image(text):
    response = openai.Image.create(
        prompt=text,
        n=4,
        size="256x256"
    )
    for i, data in enumerate(response['data']):
        image_url = data['url']

        # Download the image
        image_data = requests.get(image_url).content
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
        image.save(f"generated_image_{i}.png")
        image.show()
    print("Images saved")

# Main chat loop
while True:
    user_input = input("User: ")
    if user_input == 'quit':
        break
    elif user_input.lower().startswith('generate image'):
        
        image_text = user_input.lower().replace('generate image', '').strip()
        generate_image(image_text)
    else:
        response = get_response(user_input)
        print("ChatBot: ", response)
```

Comment: Did you want `client.completions.create()`?

Comment: see: [v1.0.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the new form of the client call:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.completions.create(
      engine="text-davinci-003",
      prompt=prompt,
      temperature=0.5,
      max_tokens=100
    )
```

Substitute like that through the rest of your code, it should be pretty straightforward.

Note that the new client automatically recognizes the API key as an environment variable if you put it in `OPENAI_API_KEY`.

For more details, check out the docs:

https://platform.openai.com/docs/libraries

and the migration guide:

https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742